# Getting "The request was aborted because there was no available instance." for a Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am having a Firebase Function that is accepting HTTP requests and accessing Firestore database that is giving this error of "The request was aborted because there was no available instance."

This firebase function adds a record in the database and sends a SMS message using a third part SMS gateway.

I am having default configuration of the function (i.e.) I have no special run time options in runWith. Please find below the code that I have for this function.

This function is running in Node 10 engine and in asia-south1 region.

```
exports.manageRequestGenerateOTP = functions.region('asia-south1').https.onRequest((request: { body: any; }, response: any) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {
        const otpGenerator = require('otp-generator');
        const requestBody = request.body;

        let otpValue = otpGenerator.generate(4, { digits: true, alphabets: false, upperCase: false, specialChars: false });

        //Validate the data in the request
        let validRequest = true;
        let errorMessage = "";
        if (!requestBody.phoneNumber || requestBody.phoneNumber == "") {
            validRequest = false;
            errorMessage = "Phone Number is missing";
        }
        if (validRequest) {
            try {
                const res = await admin.firestore().collection('managerequests').add(requestBody);
                if (res.id) {
                    const manageRequestsRef = admin.firestore().collection('managerequests').doc(res.id);
                    manageRequestsRef.get().then((doc: any) => {
                        const customerPhoneNumber = doc.data().phoneNumber;
                        const message = "The OTP to book / modify your vaccination request is " + otpValue + ". It will be valid for 3 minutes. - GCC";
                        const isOTPMessage = true;
                        sendOTP(customerPhoneNumber, message,isOTPMessage).then(async data => {
                            // Update the OTP into the database and respond back with the OTP
                            await manageRequestsRef.update({ OTP: otpValue, otpGenerationTime: new Date().getTime(), status: "Requested" });
                            const responseMessage = { 'status': 'success'};
                            response.send(responseMessage);
                        })
                            .catch(err => {
                                const responseMessage = { 'status': 'failure', "message": "OTP SMS failed", "data": err };
                                response.send(responseMessage);
                            });
                    });
                } else {
                    response.send({ 'status': 'failure', 'message': "Request could not be saved. Try again." });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                response.send({ 'status': 'failure', 'message': "Request could not be saved. Try again." });
            }
        } else {
            response.send({ 'status': 'failure', 'message': errorMessage });
        }
    })
});
```

I see another question that talks about the same error with Google Cloud Run. But I was not able to find anything that related to Firebase Functions.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried running your function in another region?

Comment: same issue i have faced today. Did you found the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the Google infrastructure, please check the following GH issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/962